# Retrieving data from Oracle database using PHP

Tags: php, oracle10g

I am having a problem retrieving data from an Oracle 10g database on a remote server.  I am using PHP on a Linux Debian web server and oci8 is enabled and working.  I am only getting a blank page.  The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('username','password','//server IP address:1521/servicename');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Prepare the statement
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM table');
if (!$stid) {
    $e = oci_error($conn);
    //trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Perform the logic of the query
$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stid);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Fetch the results of the query
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print " <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

I am not sure how to clearly define the database that I would like to connect to as there are several Oracle database on the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your error reporting turned on? are you getting any error messages that would help you debug this ?

Comment: I just get a blank page so will turn on error reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem now resolved.

I was getting a ocienvnlscreate() failed LD_LIBRARY_PATH problem once I had added error reporting. This was down to either the path set for LD_LIBRARY_PATH or permissions on the instantclient directory and it was the latter.  Many thanks for your response Maximus2012.